# Profiling application on QNX

Tags: profiling, qnx

I have an application and I want to collect stack traces for it for performance analysis. The problem is, in QNX it seems to be impossible. I tried the following approaches

- Compiled everything with `-pg` and `-no-pie`. I get some profiling information, but not for my library. I made sure the library is compiled with the same options, but library information is simply not there.
- gperftools doesn't support QNX

What tools do you use to profile your QNX applications?